# Why can't Openpyxl load my existing .xlsx document?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am using python and openpyxl to open an existing .xlsx file and add to it, but openpyxl is giving me the following error:

```
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support  file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm
```

The code I used to access the file is shown below:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = '/Users/[My Name]/Desktop/[Company Name]/2021/August/08-09-21/UPS 08-09-21/428-001_UPS_INPUT.xlsx'

wb = load_workbook(filename='path',)
```

The path is correct and it is a standard .xlsx document which I can open with excel.

Comment: You're giving ```'path'``` (a string) as the filename; you want ```filename=path``` (the variable).

Comment: Thank you!  I feel dumb.